# CSS nth child box shadow hidden

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am having trouble with the combination of the CSS selector `:nth-child(...)` and the box-shadow effect. The desired effect is as follows:

- Even-numbered div elements in a container are given an alternating background color.
- When the user hovers over one of the div elements, a box shadow is applied, giving the appearance of the "hovered" div "hovering" above the following div.

However, I am running into a problem. While the box shadow is applied to the "hovered" element, the effect is different for even-numbered div elements as opposed to odd-numbered ones. Essentially, the shadow of each even div overlaps the following odd div, while the shadow of each odd div is rendered *behind* the following even div.

This pen demonstrates the issue better: http://codepen.io/jtlovetteiii/pen/cEaLK

Here is the HTML snippet:

```
<div class="rows">
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  ...
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.rows
{
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
}

.rows .row:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: #E2E2E2;
}

.row
{
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row:hover
{
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px #888888;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It would be nice if you could post your css!

Comment: Which one is the desired effect?

Comment: @AaronMiler - Both effects are desired. The idea is for the div elements to have alternating row color (like you may see in tabular data), and for each row to be given a box shadow effect when the user mouses over it. I would like for both effects to be applied, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because only your `nth-child(even)` `div`s have a background color. While it appears that the hover shadow is overlapping the other `div`, it really isn’t – it’s overlapping the parent’s background color.

You can fix the issue with a combination of `position: relative` and `z-index`:

```css
.rows {
  position: relative;
}

.row
{
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

.row:nth-child(even)
{
  background-color: #E2E2E2;
}

.row:hover
{
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px #888888;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

[CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJCaw)

Comment: Thank you! That explains why the shadows for the other elements were appearing "behind" their immediate children.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. Not sure *why* that is happening, but I found a workaround. By adding a `position: relative` to the `:hover` elements, the hover effect is more consistent:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hsKEf

```
.rows
{
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
}

.rows .row:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: #E2E2E2;
}

.row
{
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row:hover
{
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px #888888;
  position: relative;
}
```

It still doesn't look quite right, but maybe a margin offset would cause it to look a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GvhG8/)</kbd>

```
.row
{
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;    
}

.row:hover
{
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px #888888;
  z-index:2;
}
```